# Python : Given a text file with space delimited, How to count to number of columns in each row or line of text file

Tags: string, python-3.x, text, whitespace, string-length

Is there any other way of finding the number of columns in each row of text file.

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            columns    = line.strip().split()
            print(len(columns), 'columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply: `line.count(' ')` for no. of spaces? And `+ 1` for no. of columns?

And a break down from the disassembler:

```
>>> import dis
>>> line = "1 2 3 4\n"
>>> m1 = lambda x: line.count(' ')
>>> m2 = lambda x: len(line.split()) 
>>> dis.dis(m1)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (count)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (' ')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(m2)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (split)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Where is the count here ? I'm not able to understand it !

Comment: Edited the variable in the answer. Treating each line as a `str` object, you can perform these operation http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-string-methods/ and `str.count(char)` is one of them.